Getting document library changes in SharePoint through power automate
I have a power automate flow that is triggered when an item is published in SharePoint, my flow currently does an HTTP SharePoint call to get the change that matches my change token
HTTP Call
The issue I'm running into is this call works for lists but not document Libraries, how can I modify it to work for Document Libraries?
From doing some looking online I tried
_api/web/lists('@{variables('ListID')}')/GetChanges
I also tried doing a get files then putting a filter on it of -10 seconds to get the latest change but the problem is the HTTP trigger and sharepoint action aren't always in sync, sometimes it can take several minutes
